# How can I make this 100% height + column overflow layout work in Firefox and IE?

Tags: html, css

I have a three-column layout that takes up 100% width and height of the browser (with padding). This layout contains two columns which also take up 100% height and should scroll independently.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KdZ9A/2/. Here is how it looks in Chrome (desirable -- individual columns scroll):

[image]

and Firefox and IE (undesirable -- body is scrolling):

[image]

This works perfectly in Chrome; however, the in Firefox and IE (10), the entire page scrolls instead of individual columns scrolling. I only want the columns to overflow and scroll -- not the body. Any idea how to make this work in Firefox and IE?

I've also tried a bit different approach using absolute positioning of the columns' contents: http://jsfiddle.net/KdZ9A/3/.

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="palette">palette</div>
        <div id="list">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="editor">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using absolute positioning to achieve 100% height and then display of table and table-cell inside that to achieve 100% height of the columnns:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

#container {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}

#inner {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#inner > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

#palette {
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 180px;
    width: 180px !important;
    background-color: pink;
}

#list {
    width: 55%;
    min-width: 350px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

#editor {
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: magenta;
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: +1 great question, this has been bugging me also

Comment: Are you sure you want 100% width? There is an optimal line length, in terms of readability, and there are some really wide screens nowadays. If you would settle for a fixed total width, of say some 1000px, it shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: @FrankConijn It seems as though the height is the greater issue, if the height is fixed scrolling works fine, once you set it to 100% it falls over and dies in Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I was 5 minutes from giving up and HOLY CRAP...I GOT IT WORKING

http://jsfiddle.net/gFX5E/15/

This is based on the different approach I mentioned. I needed to wrap .content divs and make the wrappers position relative. I also added some headers to the columns.

HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Seems to work in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and IE8+.

And here is a more semantic HTML5 version which also adds a header to the top: http://jsfiddle.net/gFX5E/20/. I believe this will require use of html5shiv to work in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to settle for a fixed total width, here is how:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box; /* makes filling up easier */
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #container {
      position: relative;
      width: 980px;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      background: grey;
    }
    #palette {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 800px;
      background: pink;
    }
    #list {
      position: absolute;
      left: 180px;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 450px;
      background: cyan;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #editor {
      position: absolute;
      left: 530px;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: magenta;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="palette">Palette</div>
    <div id="list" class="content"></div>
    <div id="editor" class="content"></div>
  </div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
            $('.content').append('<p>Lorem ipsum [truncated for SO]</p>');
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo on this Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqgCm?editors=100.

Comment: Works in FF and Chrome, but IE does not render the scrollbars well. Let me fiddle some more.

Comment: This looks pretty darn good man. Yeah, I'm gonna tweak this a bit...let me know what you find with IE. Thanks Frank!

Comment: @ChadJohnson - You're welcome. With the edit, the code now works in IE as well. The Codepen demo has been updated also. Checked in IE8 and 9, FF28 and Chrome30. It should even work in IE7, as well as in IE10+ (don't have that here).

Comment: @ChadJohnson - I replaced my previous comment rather than edit it, and don't know whether SO then gives you another notification. Just in case you missed it: I've edited my code twice. In the second, there is no more need for the conditional classes, and the `overflow-y` is now set to `auto` again.

Comment: Okay cool. Thanks Frank. I wish there was a way to not have to specify exact pixels for the columns...like, make them % widths.

Comment: @ChadJohnson - A layout table? ;-) I've been practicing and making divs layouts so often that I'm pretty sure that is the only way if you want percentage widths.

Comment: Yep. That's what I had before, and I had the cross-browser issues :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post, but I thought I'd comment. 
If you  `display: flex` instead of `display: table` in your 1st example that should fix the issue.

Also setting your scroll container height to 100vh will also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that the browsers apply scroll only when they understand the size( i.e. height and width) of the content is greater than the size specified for it. In your case, the height you have specified for the div is 100%. This effectively tells the browser to keep increasing the size of the div till all the content fits in completely. Hence, this creates the situation where scroll isn't needed as the browser would 'fit' the entire content within this div.

So if you want the div (or the paragraphs contained in it) to be scrollable, then you would have to specify the height and then tell the browser to provide a scroll for the content that won't fit in the specified size.

I am not sure if you want the individual 'paragraphs' to be scrollable or the entire div( which contains these paragraphs) to be scrollable. In either case, you would need to provide a fixed height for the scroll to be useful.  Your paragraph tag would need to have the following CSS applied to it :

```
p {
    height: 200px;        /*Some fixed height*/
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here's an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/y49C3/

In case you want your div called 'content' to be scrollable (as opposed to the paragraphs),  then you would have to apply the aforementioned CSS to the div instead.

```
.content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 500px;
}
```

You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/qF7Mt/1/

I have tested this in Firefox (29) and IE 10 and it works fine!!!

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: i am sure he knows that but its not what he is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, but, I need the columns to fill the entire height of the browser -- whatever that may be. So I can't have them be of fixed height (i.e., they need to be 100% height).